# AngularJS ng-show on colgroup tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Building a table where the user can choose to hide some columns (month - or the indiviual series for that each month). Is it possible to use ng-show with a colgroup or col tag - so I don't need to add the ngshow to every cell?  Can't seem to get it working...

```
<colgroup ng-repeat="mth in months" span="2" ng-show="mth.checked">
    <col  ng-show="headerOptions[0].selected" />
    <col  ng-show="headerOptions[1].selected" />
</colgroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little to do with AngularJS and more to do with HTML/CSS.

Hiding columns in a HTML table is pain. There are some questions with answers here on SO already. Take a look at [Hide/Show Column in an HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455958/hide-show-column-in-an-html-table) and [How to hide columns in HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440657/how-to-hide-columns-in-html-table).

A performance tip could be to hide the entire table before hiding/showing the columns to avoid  unnecessary reflow/repaint events.

Comment: Ok, thought maybe AngularJS could help with that - thanks for the links.