# Hide Table Column in CSS

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a table that is automatically generated by some software that I am using, the Table is QOProducts and has the four columns as below:

```
<table id="QOProducts" border="1" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>
<b>Thumbnail</b>
</th>
<th style="width:250px;">
<b>Product Name</b>
</th>
<th style="width:150px;">
<b>Description</b>
</th>
<th>
<b>Quantity</b>
```

I have tried a few ways but does anyone know if it is possible to hide the second column in the global css file as I do not have direct access the the page. Or would I need to use jQuery?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide columns in HTML table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440657/how-to-hide-columns-in-html-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a solution that doesn't require `nth-child` (which isn't supported by old browsers such as IE8), you can use the fact that these old browsers do support `first-child`.

```css
#QOProducts th:first-child + th, #QOProducts td:first-child + td {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="QOProducts" border="1" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <b>Thumbnail</b>
      </th>
      <th style="width:250px;">
        <b>Product Name</b>
      </th>
      <th style="width:150px;">
        <b>Description</b>
      </th>
      <th>
        <b>Quantity</b> 
    <tr><td>test<td>test<td>test<td>test</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was actually thinking about adding the `+` adjacent operator to the answer but I thought, meh - 2k15 with IE 11 and Edge 12 ^.^

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand Heh... Actually I had only nth-child in the solution, but as I was ready to hit the "Post" button, I saw there were 3 answers already, so I had to do _something_ to add something useful, instead of throwing my answer away.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work

```
#QOProducts tr td:nth-child(2), #QOProducts tr th:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your CSS

```
tr > th:nth-of-type(2),
tr > td:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`nth-child(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) selector here,
in your case you want to hide the second *column* so I assume that you mean the *second* `td` of every `tr`.

This would add up to

```
#QOProducts tr td:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Even tho that only targets `td`'s in a `tr` - if you're unsure about your structure you could simplify the selector and make it more global.

```
#QOProducts > * > td:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

this would target only direct `td` children of the direct children of the table (if that makes any sense to you whatsoever)

If you need to also hide the second `td` of any nested tables etcetera you could always do this

```
#QOProducts td:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

which will hide all the *second child* `td`'s for you.