# Alter an HTML table in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, code-behind

I have a table with a specific layout.  It starts like this:

```
<table>
    <tr bgcolor="#007ACC" style="color:White">
        <td width="145"><asp:Label Text="" ID="lblLevel" runat="server" /></td><td width="80"></td><td width="30"></td><td width="145"><asp:Label Text="" ID="lblGroupNumber" runat="server" /></td><td width="60"></td><td width="10">Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" width="460px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboActive" runat="server" Width="50px">
                <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The problem is, under certain conditions I need it to look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr bgcolor="#007ACC" style="color:White">
        <td width="145"><asp:Label Text="" ID="lblLevel" runat="server" /></td><td width="80"></td><td width="30"></td><td width="145"><asp:Label Text="" ID="lblGroupNumber" runat="server" /></td><td width="60"></td><td width="10">Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" width="460px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" width="460px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboActive" runat="server" Width="50px">
                <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I've hidden textboxes before, that's no problem.  But the only way I can think of to do this is to hide `td's` using code.  I've seen this:

[How to hide columns in HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440657/how-to-hide-columns-in-html-table)

but they never explain how you can determine which `td` is to be hidden.

So, can this be done in code (preferably code-behind in C#)?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asp.net most elements can be programmatically handled as server controls with  `runat` set:

```
<td colspan="2" runat="server" id="tdToHide"> 
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" width="460px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

In C#:

```
tdToHide.Visible = false;
```

This is one of many, many approaches to 'hide things' on a web page.

Another one would be a conditional CSS class on the `td`. The display of which would then be dealt with by styles on the page.

Comment: F'n brilliant, brotha!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LiteralControl and then based on condition change the content or AddControl to the [literalcontrol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). This can be performed from code behind

Answer (score 0):

Other way to select specific HTML Tags can bei done with css Selectors.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
Look at etc.:   p:nth-child(2)