# Detect click on a table column header, hide the column, then display it again

Tags: html, reactjs

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440657/how-to-hide-columns-in-html-table) response on how to hide a column. I need a little more complicated behavior. I have a `react` table like this

```
var StockTable = React.createClass({
    render: function () {        
        var items = [];
        for (var symbol in this.props.stocks) {
            var stock = this.props.stocks[symbol];
                items.push(<OptionRow key={stock.symbol} stock={stock} bid={this.props.bid} ask = {this.props.ask}  />); 
        }

        return (        
            <table table-head id="stocktable">
            ...
```

I need to detect when a user clicks on the header of the table, get the column she clicked on, and hide that column. Then, if a user clicks a separate button on the page, I need all the columns that are hidden to display again.

It would also be nice if the cursor changed to something like a hand when in the table header to alert the user that an action is possible. Like it does when you hover over a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a list of hidden table headers in state

```
this.state = {hidden: []}
```

and event handlers for each header

```
<th onClick={() => hideHeader('cost')}>
```

to avoid rendering them

```
hidden.indexOf('cost') !=== -1 ? <someheader/> : null
```

Rendering null is a valid way to avoid rendering something.

To change pointers: [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item)

Comment: Thanks I was able to use the rough outline to make it work!