# Hide table column with vue js

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2

Hello i need to hide or show columns of my datatable, I do not know what the good practice to do this, When columns checkboxes is checked the columns will shown and if it's not checked the column will be hidden?
I'm using vuetify
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmXwYG?editors=1010

This my script :

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        search: '',
        totalItems: 0,
        items: [],
        loading: true,
        pagination: {},
        columns: [],
        headers: [{
                text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                left: true,
                sortable: false,
                value: 'name'
            },
            {
                text: 'Calories',
                value: 'calories'
            },
            {
                text: 'Fat (g)',
                value: 'fat'
            },
            {
                text: 'Carbs (g)',
                value: 'carbs'
            },
            {
                text: 'Protein (g)',
                value: 'protein'
            },
            {
                text: 'Sodium (mg)',
                value: 'sodium'
            },
            {
                text: 'Calcium (%)',
                value: 'calcium'
            },
            {
                text: 'Iron (%)',
                value: 'iron'
            }
        ]
    }
    },
    watch: {
        pagination: {
            handler() {
                this.getDataFromApi()
                    .then(data => {
                        this.items = data.items
                        this.totalItems = data.total
                    })
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getDataFromApi()
            .then(data => {
                this.items = data.items
                this.totalItems = data.total
            })
    },
    methods: {
        getDataFromApi() {
            this.loading = true
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const {
                    sortBy,
                    descending,
                    page,
                    rowsPerPage
                } = this.pagination

                let items = this.getUsers()
                const total = items.length

                if (this.pagination.sortBy) {
                    items = items.sort((a, b) => {
                        const sortA = a[sortBy]
                        const sortB = b[sortBy]

                        if (descending) {
                            if (sortA < sortB) return 1
                            if (sortA > sortB) return -1
                            return 0
                        } else {
                            if (sortA < sortB) return -1
                            if (sortA > sortB) return 1
                            return 0
                        }
                    })
                }

                if (rowsPerPage > 0) {
                    items = items.slice((page - 1) * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage)
                }

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.loading = false
                    resolve({
                        items,
                        total
                    })
                }, 1000)
            })
        },
        getUsers() {
            return [{
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    calories: 159,
                    fat: 6.0,
                    carbs: 24,
                    protein: 4.0,
                    sodium: 87,
                    calcium: '14%',
                    iron: '1%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                    calories: 237,
                    fat: 9.0,
                    carbs: 37,
                    protein: 4.3,
                    sodium: 129,
                    calcium: '8%',
                    iron: '1%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Eclair',
                    calories: 262,
                    fat: 16.0,
                    carbs: 23,
                    protein: 6.0,
                    sodium: 337,
                    calcium: '6%',
                    iron: '7%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Cupcake',
                    calories: 305,
                    fat: 3.7,
                    carbs: 67,
                    protein: 4.3,
                    sodium: 413,
                    calcium: '3%',
                    iron: '8%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Gingerbread',
                    calories: 356,
                    fat: 16.0,
                    carbs: 49,
                    protein: 3.9,
                    sodium: 327,
                    calcium: '7%',
                    iron: '16%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Jelly bean',
                    calories: 375,
                    fat: 0.0,
                    carbs: 94,
                    protein: 0.0,
                    sodium: 50,
                    calcium: '0%',
                    iron: '0%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Lollipop',
                    calories: 392,
                    fat: 0.2,
                    carbs: 98,
                    protein: 0,
                    sodium: 38,
                    calcium: '0%',
                    iron: '2%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Honeycomb',
                    calories: 408,
                    fat: 3.2,
                    carbs: 87,
                    protein: 6.5,
                    sodium: 562,
                    calcium: '0%',
                    iron: '45%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Donut',
                    calories: 452,
                    fat: 25.0,
                    carbs: 51,
                    protein: 4.9,
                    sodium: 326,
                    calcium: '2%',
                    iron: '22%'
                },
                {
                    value: false,
                    name: 'KitKat',
                    calories: 518,
                    fat: 26.0,
                    carbs: 65,
                    protein: 7,
                    sodium: 54,
                    calcium: '12%',
                    iron: '6%'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440657/how-to-hide-columns-in-html-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is use computed properties to decide what columns are going to be included.

Your data table is taking a list of headers and a list of items (rows). I've added a couple of computed properties to your Vue to return the list of columns that *should* be included in the data table results.

```
computed:{
  filteredHeaders(){
    return this.headers.filter(h => h.selected)
  },
  filteredItems(){
    return this.items.map(item => {
      let filtered = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.headers.forEach(header => {
        if (!header.selected) delete filtered[header.value]
      })
      return filtered
    })
  }
},
```

Notice that these computed values are using a property of the header called `selected`. I added that property to your list of headers to allow you to select the headers that are going to be included in the output.

```
{
  text: 'Fat (g)',
  value: 'fat',
  selected: true
},
```

Next, your checkboxes need to use that property as their model.

```
<v-checkbox v-bind:label="header.text" v-model="header.selected" :value="header.selected" ></v-checkbox>
```

Finally, you have a template for each row. I modified that to check to see if each column is enabled.

```
<template slot="items" scope="props">
  <td v-if="showColumn('name')">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
  <td v-if="showColumn('calories')"  class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
  <td v-if="showColumn('fat')"  class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
  <td v-if="showColumn('carbs')"  class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
  <td v-if="showColumn('protein')"  class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
  <td v-if="showColumn('sodium')"  class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.sodium }}</td>
  <td v-if="showColumn('calcium')"  class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calcium }}</td>
  <td v-if="showColumn('iron')"  class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
</template>
```

And here is the `showColumn` method that is used in that template.

```
showColumn(col){
  return this.headers.find(h => h.value === col).selected
},
```

Finally, here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BZBzeN?editors=1010).

Obviously this is not tuned or anything, it's just an initial "get it working" version. But it should get you going.

Comment: @codinga Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much, I confess that you always help me

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `fields` prop to define only the columns you wish to display.

Answer (score 0):

Loop all the fields as well

example :
`<b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>`

Enjoy.