# How to hide index level in pandas <1.4

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm trying to hide an index level from a pandas Styler with pandas 1.3.5. *i.e.* to replicate the behavior of `hide(axis="index", level="level_name")` in pandas 1.4.

Here is a minimale example of what I'm trying :

```py
def multi_highlighter(row, range_colors):
    def find_color(value):
        for color, threshold in range_colors.items():
            if value < threshold:
                return color
        return "white"

    return [f"background-color: {find_color(v)}" for v in row]

range_colors = {"red": 18, "orange": 100}

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Ex Date": ['2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-07-30', '2022-07-30', '2022-07-30'], 
    "Portfolio": ['UUU-SSS', 'UUU-SSS', 'UUU-SSS', 'RRR-DDD', 'RRR-DDD', 'RRR-DDD', 'KKK-VVV', 'KKK-VVV', 'KKK-VVV'],
    "Position": [120, 90, 110, 113, 111, 92, 104, 110, 110],
    "Strike": [18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 15, 18, 19],
    })
(
    data
    .reset_index()
    .set_index(["Ex Date", "Portfolio", "index"])
    .style
    .apply(multi_highlighter, range_colors=range_colors, axis=1)
)
```

Adding some borders, it produces the following table:

[image]

Now to hide the "index" index level, I tried to achieve this by adding CSS styling from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29500414/13354525), as follows:

```py
.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'tr th:nth-child(3), tr td:nth-child(3)', 'props': [
    ('display', 'None')]}], overwrite=False)
```

But it gives me this results instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options in pandas 1.3.5, though this is a non-trivial operation without the use of the `hide` function available in 1.4.0.

#### Removing Index Levels >= 1

`nth-child` is not working here due to the use of rowspans in the MultiIndex. However, we can take advantage of the default CSS classes that are added by the Styler ([style.py L158-L171](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/66e3805b8cabe977f40c05259cc3fcf7ead5687d/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L158-L171)):

> - Index and Column names include `index_name` and `level<k>` where `k` is its level in a MultiIndex
> - Index label cells include
>
>   - `row_heading`
>   - `row<n>` where `n` is the numeric position of the row
>   - `level<k>` where `k` is the level in a MultiIndex
> - Column label cells include
>
>   - `col_heading`
>   - `col<n>` where `n` is the numeric position of the column
>   - `level<k>` where `k` is the level in a MultiIndex
> - Blank cells include `blank`

So we can simply exclude the CSS selector `.level2:not(.col_heading)` where `n` is whatever level we want to hide (level0 would require a slight modification). We need to exclude the col_heading so we don't remove any column headers.

Additionally, we then need to remove one of the `blank` levels that so the top level lines up. I've taken the easy route and have chosen to remove the first blank for each row.

**Note: This is not a durable solution and will be impacted by structure changes like MultiIndex columns.**

Here is an example hiding level 2 with styles

```py
hide_column_styles = [
    {
        # Remove all row values associated with level2
        'selector': f'th.level2:not(.col_heading)',
        'props': [('display', 'none')]
    },
    {
        # Remove the first th in each row if it is .blank
        'selector': 'thead th:first-child.blank',
        'props': [('display', 'none')]
    }
]

# Basic border
border_styles = [{
    'selector': '',
    'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse')]
}, {
    'selector': 'table, th, td',
    'props': [('border', '1px solid black')]
}]
(
    data.reset_index()
        .set_index(["Ex Date", "Portfolio", "index"])
        .style
        .apply(multi_highlighter, range_colors=range_colors, axis=1)
        .set_table_styles([*hide_column_styles, *border_styles])
)
```

[image: Styler object using display:none to hide level 2]

---

#### Removing Index level 0

If trying to remove level0 we only need to hide level0:

```py
hide_column_styles = [
    {
        # Remove all values associated with level0 (including the first header row)
        'selector': f'th.level0:not(.col_heading)',
        'props': [('display', 'none')]
    }
]
```

The first index column will have the class .level0 and be hidden without needing an additional selector:

```html
<tr>
  <th class="blank">&nbsp;</th>
  <th class="blank">&nbsp;</th>
  <th class="blank level0">&nbsp;</th> <!-- This will match and be hidden -->
  <th class="col_heading level0 col0">Position</th>
  <th class="col_heading level0 col1">Strike</th>
</tr>
```

---

#### Hiding levels that do not affect MultiIndex Uniqueness

If the index levels would remain unique after removing a level it is possible just to [droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to remove the index *before* creating a Styler:

For example, here's an example of removing level 0 by dropping it.

```py
n = 0  # level to drop
(
    data
        .reset_index()
        .set_index(["Ex Date", "Portfolio", "index"])
        .droplevel(level=n)  # Drop level from DataFrame
        .style
        .apply(multi_highlighter, range_colors=range_colors, axis=1)
        .set_table_styles([
        {
            'selector': 'table, th, td',
            'props': [('border', '1px solid black')]
        }
    ])
)
```

Note: this will only work if the MultiIndex is unique **after** the level is removed

[image: Styler object with level 0 dropped before styling]

If a level is dropped causing a non-unique MultiIndex (like level 2) a KeyError will occur when using `Styler.apply` or `Styler.applymap`:

> KeyError: '`Styler.apply` and `.applymap` are not compatible with non-unique index or columns.'

---

#### Pandas 1.4.0 and newer

Just to be super clear for any future readers of this question, this is a workaround for versions prior to 1.4.0. It is *much* simpler to use the [hide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) function and the solution is much more durable than CSS selectors:

```
n = 2  # level to drop
border_styles = [{
    'selector': '',
    'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse')]
}, {
    'selector': 'table, th, td',
    'props': [('border', '1px solid black')]
}]

(
    data
        .reset_index()
        .set_index(["Ex Date", "Portfolio", "index"])
        .style
        .apply(multi_highlighter, range_colors=range_colors, axis=1)
        .hide(axis=0, level=n)
        .set_table_styles(border_styles)
)
```

[image: Styler object using the hide function with level=2 to hide level 2]

Answer (score 0):

To entirely delete the index column instead of hiding it using CSS style, I used BeautifulSoup:

```
def drop_idex_level(html_body: str, level: int):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_body, 'html.parser')
    css_selector = f"th.level{level}:not(.col_heading), thead th:first-child.blank"
    for e in soup.select(css_selector):
        e.decompose()
    return soup.prettify( formatter="html")
```

This function takes an html body and the index level to drop, select the element using the selector in @Henry's answer and deletes them from the body.