# Hide or drop index level when saving pandas styler to excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, pandas-styles

Following to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72700845/13354525), I'm trying to hide an index level when saving the Styler object to excel, but unfortunately the `index` argument only accepts *True* or *False*, either showing or hiding the whole index.

Code example to build the styled table:

```
def multi_highlighter(row, range_colors):
    def find_color(value):
        for color, threshold in range_colors.items():
            if value < threshold:
                return color
        return "white"

    return [f"background-color: {find_color(v)}" for v in row]

range_colors = {"red": 18, "orange": 100}

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Ex Date": ['2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2022-07-30', '2022-07-30', '2022-07-30'], 
    "Portfolio": ['UUU-SSS', 'UUU-SSS', 'UUU-SSS', 'RRR-DDD', 'RRR-DDD', 'RRR-DDD', 'KKK-VVV', 'KKK-VVV', 'KKK-VVV'],
    "Position": [120, 90, 110, 113, 111, 92, 104, 110, 110],
    "Strike": [18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 15, 18, 19],
    })
table_styles = [
    {
        'selector': 'table, th, td', 
        'props': [('border', 'thin solid gray')]
    },
    {
        'selector': '', 
        'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse !important')]
    },
    {
        'selector': "th.level2:not(.col_heading), thead th:first-child.blank",
        'props': [('display', 'None')]
    }
]

styler = (
    data
    .reset_index()
    .set_index(["Ex Date", "Portfolio", "index"])
    .style
    .apply(multi_highlighter, range_colors=range_colors, axis=1)
    .set_table_styles(table_styles, overwrite=False)
)
```

Then saving to excel as follows:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx') as writer:
    styler.to_excel(writer, index=True, sheet_name='sheet_name')
    # adjusting columns widths
    threshold_len = 20 # no column should have width more than 20
    for idx, col in enumerate(styler.data):
        longest_col_cell = styler.data[col].astype(str).str.len().max()
        col_head_len = len(str(col))
        max_len = max(longest_col_cell, col_head_len)
        writer.sheets['sheet_name'].set_column(idx, idx, min(max_len, threshold_len))
```

With `index=True`, it produce the following results:

[image]

Even though the "index" index level is hidden in the html:

[image]

I tried to look for some method like `set_column` to delete or hide the column after writing to the excel file but with no luck.

Comment: Hi, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527841/11246056

Comment: @Laurent I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'column_dimensions'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I found for this is to remove the column with openpyxl after saving the file :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

with pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx') as writer:
    styler.to_excel(writer, index=True, sheet_name='sheet_name')

wb = load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet_name']
ws.delete_cols(3)
wb.save('filename.xlsx')
```